# Charts in Dashboard should update after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I am showing default charts on my dashboard and there is a form also and I want to update/filter the charts after the form submission.

Js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: (contextPath + "/setting/dashboard"),
      success: function(result){                          
         drawLineChart()

          }       
      }          
  });  

  $("#chartupdate").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      var url = form.attr('action') ;   
      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "POST",
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function(data){
            console.log("form" + data);
              }
      }) ; 
  }); });
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: what doesn't work ? did you got any error ? where is your form code ?

Answer (score 0):

A bracket inline 9 was preventing the execution of .submit function. Remove the bracket

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
              $.ajax({
                url: (contextPath + "/setting/dashboard"),
                success: function(result){                          
                         drawLineChart()
                               }       
                      });  

    $("#chartupdate").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action') ;   
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
              console.log("form" + data);
                }
        }) ; 
    }); 

  });
```